# Excel compare two tables and return value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two sheets as below in Sheet-4 if NE and Slot column match the Sheet-1 column which is AB1S2a    SLOT-1 then i want the result SN which is in sheet-4  SN=CAT1016127B to be printed in Sheet -1 beside the slot, Is there any way?

Sheet-4:

[image]

Sheet-1:

[image]

Comment: There is surely a way. A better question, complete with punctuation, might help you find out what it is :).

Comment: Is it fine now sir....

Comment: Suggested reading list: ① [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le) ② [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an “actual” question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ③ [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ④ [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  ⑤ [Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

Assume in `Sheet1` cell `D2` you want serial no. Then use this array formula to achieve that.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!C:C,MATCH(B2&C2,Sheet4!A:A&Sheet4!B:B,0)),"")
```

**As it is a array formula. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet4!C:C;Sheet4!A:A;B2;Sheet4!B:B;C2)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to what your code _does_. Just code is not a useful answer for users with the same question.